# c# Context Error on Variable used within a Method

Tags: c#, sql

Im having a bit of an issue with public -v- private variables and scope.

Here is my code

```
private void PopulateCaseViewer(string paramField, string paramValue)
    {
        string strConnection = BuildConnectionString();
        SqlConnection linkToDB = new SqlConnection(strConnection);

        if (paramField == "load")
        {
            string sqlStat = "SELECT c.CaseNo, c.Claimant, c.Defendant, c.DOA, c.CaseType, c.CaseManager, c.Occupation, c.DateInstruction " +
                             "a.IPName, a.IPRegion, l.IPReference " +
                             "FROM tblCases AS c INNER JOIN tblIPLinks as l ON c.CaseNo = l.CaseNo " +
                             "JOIN tblIPAddresses AS a ON l.IPID = a.IPID;";
        }
        using (linkToDB)
        using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlStat, linkToDB))
        {
            var table = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(table);
            dataCaseViewer.DataSource = table;
        }
    }
```

The issue is, that the string sqlStat in the line "using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter . ...)" states that sqlStat does 'not exist in the current context'.

I aim to add many IF statements on this method depending on the paramField and paramValues that are passed to it, in order to build different sqlStats to populate dataCaseViewer.DataSource dependent on User input.  But if the sqlStat variale from the IF statements can't be seen by the subsequent call in the SqlDataAdapter then I'm a bit stuck.

Any advice please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you defined sqlStat inside the IF statement above it, and that makes it valid only within that statement.

Define sqlStat above the IF, set it inside the IF, and it should work just fine.

```
string sqlStat = System.String.Empty;

if (paramField == "load")
{
    sqlStat = "SELECT...";
```

Answer (score 1):

Well put it this way - what do you want to be used instead of the value assigned in the `if` statement if `paramField` *isn't* "load"? What SQL statement would you expect to construct?

You probably need to just *declare* the `paramField` outside the `if` statement, and make sure that whatever path is taken, an appropriate value will be assigned to it before you use it.

Answer (score 1):

```
    string sqlStat;    
    if (paramField == "load")
    {
        sqlStat = "SELECT c.CaseNo, c.Claimant, c.Defendant, c.DOA, c.CaseType, c.CaseManager, c.Occupation, c.DateInstruction " +
                         "a.IPName, a.IPRegion, l.IPReference " +
                         "FROM tblCases AS c INNER JOIN tblIPLinks as l ON c.CaseNo = l.CaseNo " +
                         "JOIN tblIPAddresses AS a ON l.IPID = a.IPID;";
    }
    using (linkToDB)
    using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlStat, linkToDB))
    {
      ...
```

should work.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void PopulateCaseViewer(string paramField, string paramValue)
    {
        string strConnection = BuildConnectionString();
        SqlConnection linkToDB = new SqlConnection(strConnection);

        if (paramField == "load")
        {
            string sqlStat = "SELECT c.CaseNo, c.Claimant, c.Defendant, c.DOA, c.CaseType, c.CaseManager, c.Occupation, c.DateInstruction " +
                             "a.IPName, a.IPRegion, l.IPReference " +
                             "FROM tblCases AS c INNER JOIN tblIPLinks as l ON c.CaseNo = l.CaseNo " +
                             "JOIN tblIPAddresses AS a ON l.IPID = a.IPID;";

          using (linkToDB)
          using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlStat, linkToDB))
          {
            var table = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(table);
            dataCaseViewer.DataSource = table;
          }
        }
    }
```

The slqStat is defined inside the IF.. so you need everything inside the if to use

Comment: I dont want everything inside the IF otherwise I have to repeat the sqlDataAdapter code for every IF statement that will be in this method, and there are likely to be a few.

Comment: You can just initialize the variable. I guess this solution is better than having nothing working.

Answer (score 1):

You assigned the string inside the if statement, and tries to use it outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

Not a context problem, just a failure of logic.

You only declare sqlstat if paramfield = "load", so if it doesn't. It's not declared and so you can't use it....

use it inside the if or declare it outside, if you do the latter, you need to set it to something else.

```
string sqlStat = String.Empty;
if (paramfield = "load")
{
sqlstat = "...";
}
else
{
//?
}
using...
```

Comment: If I declare before the IF statement, how do I set it inside the IF statement.  Sorry if thats very basic.